# How to store state of previous component when moved to next component in SPA?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, react-hooks

I have a `MobileNumberLogin` and `LoginOTPScreen`. These are two separate screen.Whenever a user enters mobile number and click continue button he is redirected to the `LoginOTPScreen`. But suppose user hits back button from `LoginOTPScreen` he goes back to `MobileNumberLogin` screen and the number which the user entered disappears.

Following is my code for `MobileNumberLogin`

```
const MobileNumberLogin = ({ history }) => {
  const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState("");

return (
       <input
          type="tel"
          maxLength="10"
          className="mobileNumberTextField"
          placeholder="Your Mobile Number"
          autoFocus={true}
          value={mobileNumber}
          onChange={event => setMobileNumber(event.target.value)}
        />.....
```

The code for back button of `LoginOTPScreen` is as follows

```
`history.goBack();` is called on the button's click
```

but as soon as I go back to `MobileNumberLogin`, the entered number disappears from the input.

Comment: get the location of history by history.location and store for any var to redirect history.push(router)

Comment: @Mohammed_Alreai Actually I was thinking of that way but it doesn't seem right as first I have to pass mobile number to my OTPScreen and then again when user goes back send mobile number from OTPScreen to MobileNumberScreen. There must be some easy way of maintaining state. Is it because of functional components and not using class based components?

Comment: You can use Context API or Redux to share state. Do you use react-router?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii Yes I am using Context Api and React-Router in my app. Can you point me in the right direction of how to store data using Context Api? I am using Context Api to manage state for network calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ContextAPI wrapping your routes like so

```
const ContextA = React.createContext('light');

<ContextA.Provider value={{
 sharedData: this.state.sharedData, 
 setSharedData: this.setState({sharedData: 'sharedDta'})
}}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/route1' component={ MobileNumberLoginWrapped } />
    <Route exact path='/route1' component={ LoginOTPScreenWrapped } />
  </Switch>
</ContextA.Provider>
```

And then wrap your MobileNumberLogin with Context Consumer

```
<ContextA.Consumer>
{ ({sharedData, setSharedData}) =>  <MobileNumberLogin sharedData={sharedData} setSharedData={setSharedData}/>
<ContextA.Consumer>
```

Have a read the official react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

> But suppose user hits back button ...

User can also hit Refresh button too. If you need to handle that as well, then you might consider this [package](https://github.com/donavon/use-persisted-state).
LocalStorage is insecure so it shouldn't be used to store any piece of data that is security sensitive.